# need to understand ground orientation between gazebo and rviz

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Update : added URDF and SDF files being used. I have looked these over but I can not see how they would cause the model to run in different directions.

When I send -1,-1 to my joints via the ros gazebo plugin joint/command my model moves backwards but when I process those same commands in rviz via joint/state messages rviz base link moves forward. What would case this. How does ground orientation map between gazebo and rivz?

```
<sdf version="1.4">
    <model name='rrbot'>

      <static>0</static>

      <link name='base_link'>
        <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertial>
          <mass>10</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>1</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>

        <visual name='base_visual'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.4 0.2 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Red</name>
              <uri>__default__</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>

        <collision name='base_collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.4 0.2 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>0.2</mu>
                <mu2>0.2</mu2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>


        <visual name='caster_visual'>
          <pose>-0.15 0 -.05 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.05</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Blue</name>
              <uri>__default__</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>

        <collision name='caster_collision'>
          <pose>-0.15 0 -.05 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.05</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>0</mu>
                <mu2>0</mu2>
                <slip1>1.0</slip1>
                <slip2>1.0</slip2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>

        <visual name='tower_visual'>
          <pose>0.05 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.2</length>
              <radius>0.025</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/White</name>
              <uri>__default__</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>

        <collision name='tower_collision'>
          <pose>0.05 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.2</length>
              <radius>0.025</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>0</mu>
                <mu2>0</mu2>
                <slip1>1</slip1>
                <slip2>1</slip2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>


        <sensor name='camera1' type='camera'>
          <visualize>1</visualize>
          <update_rate>30</update_rate>
          <camera name='head'>
            <horizontal_fov>1.39626</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>800</width>
              <height>800</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.02</near>
              <far>300</far>
            </clip>
            <noise>
              <type>gaussian</type>
              <mean>0</mean>
              <stddev>0.007</stddev>
            </noise>
          </camera>
          <plugin name='camera_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_camera.so'>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>1</updateRate>
            <cameraName>camera1</cameraName>
            <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
            <frameName>camera_frame</frameName>
            <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
            <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
            <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
            <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
            <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
            <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
            <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
          </plugin>
          <pose>0.05 0 0.2 0 0 0</pose>
        </sensor>



        <sensor name='head_hokuyo_sensor' type='ray'>
          <visualize>1</visualize>
          <update_rate>40</update_rate>
          <ray>
            <scan>
              <horizontal>
                <samples>720</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-1.5708</min_angle>
                <max_angle>1.5708</max_angle>
              </horizontal>
            </scan>
            <range>
              <min>0.1</min>
              <max>30</max>
              <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
            <noise>
              <type>gaussian</type>
              <mean>0</mean>
              <stddev>0.01</stddev>
            </noise>
          </ray>
          <plugin name='gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_laser.so'>
            <topicName>/scan</topicName>
            <frameName>hokuyo_frame</frameName>
            <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
          </plugin>
          <pose>0.05 0 0.2 0 0 0</pose>
        </sensor>
      </link>


      <link name='left_wheel'>
        <pose>0.15 -0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <inertial>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.1</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>

        <collision name='left_wheel_collision'>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.05</length>
              <radius>0.1</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>1</mu>
                <mu2>1</mu2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>

        <visual name='left_wheel_visual'>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.05</length>
              <radius>0.1</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Red</name>
              <uri>__default__</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <gravity>1</gravity>
        <velocity_decay>
          <linear>0</linear>
          <angular>0</angular>
        </velocity_decay>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <joint name='joint1' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 -0.03 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <child>left_wheel</child>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        </axis>
      </joint>

      <link name='right_wheel'>
        <pose>0.15 0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <inertial>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.1</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='right_wheel_collision'>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.05</length>
              <radius>0.1</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>1</mu>
                <mu2>1</mu2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>
        <visual name='right_wheel_visual'>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.05</length>
              <radius>0.1</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Red</name>
              <uri>__default__</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <gravity>1</gravity>
        <velocity_decay>
          <linear>0</linear>
          <angular>0</angular>
        </velocity_decay>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <joint name='joint2' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0.03 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <child>right_wheel</child>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        </axis>
      </joint>

      <plugin name='ros_control' filename='libgazebo_ros_control.so'>
        <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
        <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
      </plugin>

    </model>
</sdf>





<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Revolute-Revolute Manipulator -->
<robot name="rrbot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find rrbot_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />

  <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.1415926535897931"/>  <!-- ${PI} -->



   <link name='base_link'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name='visual'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>



      <visual name='caster_visual'>
        <origin xyz="0.15 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius=".05"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>


      <collision name='caster_collision'>
        <origin xyz="0.15 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius=".05"/>
        </geometry>

        <surface>
         <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0</mu>
            <mu2>0</mu2>
            <slip1>1.0</slip1>
            <slip2>1.0</slip2>
          </ode>
         </friction>
        </surface>

      </collision>


     <inertial>
        <mass value="10" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia ixx=".1" ixy="0" ixz="0" 
                 iyy=".1" iyz="0" 
                 izz=".1" />
     </inertial>
  </link> 


    
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.15 -0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.15 -0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1" />
      <inertia ixx=".1" ixy="0" ixz="0" 
               iyy=".1" iyz="0" 
               izz=".1" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

 
  <joint type="continuous" name="joint1">
    <origin xyz="0.15 -0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <axis>
         <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
     </axis>
    <limit effort="3" velocity="3"/>
  </joint>


  <link name="right_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.15 0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.15 0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1" />
      <inertia ixx=".1" ixy="0" ixz="0" 
               iyy=".1" iyz="0" 
               izz=".1" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint type="continuous" name="joint2">
    <origin xyz="0.15 0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <axis>
         <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
     </axis>
    <limit effort="3" velocity="3"/>
  </joint>


  <link name="tower_link">

    <visual name="tower_visual">
      <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder  length="0.2" radius="0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="tower_collision">
      <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder  length="0.2" radius="0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

  </link>


  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0.0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="tower_link" />
  </joint>


  <link name="hokuyo_frame"/>
  <joint name="hokuyo_frame_joint" type="fixed">
    <child link="hokuyo_frame">hokuyo_frame</child>
    <parent link="tower_link">tower_link</parent>
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_frame"/>
  <joint name="camera_frame_joint" type="fixed">
    <child link="camera_frame">camera_frame</child>
    <parent link="tower_link">tower_link</parent>
  </joint>


  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint1"/>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>   
      <motorTorqueConstant>10</motorTorqueConstant>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="tran2">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint2"/>
    <actuator name="motor2">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      <motorTorqueConstant>10</motorTorqueConstant>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

  <plugin name="ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
      <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
      <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
  </plugin>


</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4654/need-to-understand-ground-orientation-between-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had inverted sign in odomentry on x.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) with karma: 107 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Rviz displays information it receives from tf. When you apply a force in Gazebo, the model moves and new pose info is passed along to rviz.

It's tough to answer your question without more information. What model are you using (the urdf would be most useful), how are you sending the joint commands, what version of Gazebo and ros are you using?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1